# How do I call react function in js map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, graphql, apollo-client

I have the below code, the problem is in the part where I am calling the RemoveProduct function in the map function:

```
function AddOrder() {
    const d = new Date();
    let text = d.toString();
    const [addOrder] = useMutation(queries.ADD_ORDER);
    const [editUser] = useMutation(queries.EDIT_USER_CART);
    const [editProduct] = useMutation(queries.EDIT_PRODUCT);

    function RemoveProduct (x)  {

        let getProd = useQuery(queries.GET_PRODUCTS_BY_ID, {
          fetchPolicy: "network-only",
          variables: {
            _id : x._id
          },
        });
        console.log(getProd.quantity)
        console.log(x.quantity)
        let a = getProd.quantity - x.quantity
        console.log(a)
        editProduct({
          variables: {
            _id : x._id,
            quantity: a
          },
        });
        return null;
    }

    const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

    if (error) {
        return <h1> error</h1>;
    } else if (loading) {
        return <h1> loading</h1>;
    } else if (data && getUserOrders.data && currentUser && data.getUser.cart.length > 0) {
        let newCart = [];
        let total = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < data.getUser.cart.length; i++) {
            total += data.getUser.cart[i].price * data.getUser.cart[i].quantity;
            newCart.push({
                orderedQuantity: data.getUser.cart[i].quantity,
                _id: data.getUser.cart[i]._id,
                name: data.getUser.cart[i].name,
                image: data.getUser.cart[i].image,
                price: data.getUser.cart[i].price,
            });
        }
        
        newCart.map((x) => RemoveProduct(x))

    

        editUser({
            variables: {
                id: currentUser.uid,
                cart: [],
            },
        });
    }
    
}
export default AddOrder;
```

I get the following error when I run this code:

```
Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
```

How can I fix this? I tried to create a separate component for RemoveProducts and call in this function but that did not work either.

Comment: You are not returning anything and only using `newCart.map`, is there supposed to be a button to remove the item? please clearfy so that i could show you how to build this.

Comment: Issue happens because `useQuery` (via its parent) is called conditionally. You should call hooks in custom hooks or functional react components, but then `RemoveProduct` if it is functional component, isn't called as such - it is called as function (e.g. `RemoveProduct()`). Also it seems you are doing some global(?) mutations/side effects in render, which isn't good idea in react

Comment: Your code is very messy. You are calling useQuery inside a function. Define useQuery outside the function. Also, your code doesn't seem to be completed at all. Provide some more code. I don't find data,getUserOrders in your code. you are not returning anything in the last else if as well.

Comment: I didn't want the code to be verbose and so haven't mentioned some of it, also I am calling useQuery multiple times because for each item in the cart I need the quantity in the collection so that I can subtract current cart quantity from that to get the final stock value to store

Answer (score 1):

1. Only call hooks at the top level
2. Don't call hooks inside loops, conditions or nested functions
3. Always use hooks at the top level of your React function, before any
   early returns
4. Only call hooks from React function components or from custom hooks.

I read this from the docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html#rules-of-hooks)

So try not to nest the function RemoveProduct or remove the hook called inside it